# Specifying Multiple Sheets/String Array?

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function, worksheet

I and working with some code that aims to Hide/Unhide Sheets based on a selection from a dropdown menu. The setup is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address = Range("SelectCP").Address Then
    Select Case Target.Value
      Case "All"
        ShowAllSheets
      Case ""
        'do nothing
      Case Else
        ShowSelSheets
        'do nothing
    End Select
  End If
End Sub
```

Where functions ShowAllSheets and ShowSelSheets are defined as:

```
Sub ShowAllSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
  ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Next ws
End Sub


Sub ShowSelSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strType As String
strType = Worksheets("Counterparty Overview").Range("SelectCP").Value
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
  If InStr(1, ws.Name, strType) > 0 Then
    ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
  Else
    If ws.Name <> "Counterparty Overview" Then
      ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End If
  End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

The trouble I'm having is with this bit:

```
Else
If ws.Name <> "Counterparty Overview" Then
  ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
```

I want to specify two other sheets in addition to "Counterparty Overview" to always show. I've tried to initiate strType as a variable array, but get an error. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim SomeSheet as String
SomeSheet = "Other Sheet Name"

If ws.Name <> "Counterparty Overview" Then
  ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
  Sheets(SomeSheet).Visible = xlVisible
  'or
  Sheets("Other Sheet Name").Visible = xlVisible

End If
```